# Derivative problem by a windmill

Tags: functions, derivatives, polynomials

Problem:

The power (in kW) of a windmill is P = 0.35 * v ^ 3. Where v is the wind speed in m/s.

We must use derivatives to calculate the increase of the power, if the wind speed increases from 19 m/s to 20 m/s.

According to the solution, you have to calculate D P (19).  But is the meaning of DP (19) really the increase between 19 and 20?  I would think this is the increase at moment of wind speed 19 m/s.

Comment: This seems a duplicate to your earlier question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4109765/increase-in-wind-speed-through-derivatives

Answer (score 1):

You have  $$P(v)=0.35\,v^3$$ Now, close to a reference point $v_0$, by Taylor expansion, you have as an *approximation*
$$P(v)=P(v_0)+P'(v_0)(v-v_0)+\frac 12 P''(v_0)(v-v_0)^2+\cdots$$

Using your numbers, we then have
$$P(20)=2400.65+379.05+19.95$$

You see how small is the third term and then how good is the linear approximation.

Comment: Thanks. What do you use as values for $v_0$ and $v$?

Comment: @WinstonCherf. What you gave  ! $v_0=19$ and $v=20$